# How should I return NSError from constructor?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a best practice to return an error to user during object construction?

```
  - (id)initWithDatabaseUrl:(NSString *)urlString
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSURL *baseUrl =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        if(baseUrl == nil){
           NSError *urlError = [self generateError:@"Invalid URL" code:NSURLErrorBadURL];
        }else{...}
}
```

So in my example, if the user provides a bad URL to my initializer I want to stop creation of this instance and return and error to the user. Should I just return nil and write to stdout?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you should do that.  Or you could pass an `NSError **` if you *really* want to, but it is weird to do that.

Comment: in my experience returning nil is enough, "unsafe" functions should be checked outside to make sure they worked. if (!something){back up plan}.